# error: invalid method declaration; return type required (line 31)

Tags: java, types, return

I know it's a bit of code but it's really driving me crazy:( 
It keeps throwing the error that method dfs() is expecting a return type on line 31, HOWEVER it is declared to return a void! What is going on here? I seem to have checked all the brackets and the scope looks good idk what is causing this! 
Thank you for the help!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project10 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("dictionary.txt")));
    BufferedReader boardLoad = new BufferedReader(args[0]);
    ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> hashDict = new HashSet<String>();

    while (br.ready()) {
      String word = br.readLine();
      dictionary.add(word);
      hashDict.add(word);
   }

   Collections.sort(dictionary);

int boardSize = Integer.parseInt(boardLoad.readLine());
String[][] board = new String[boardSize][boardSize];
  for (int i = 0; i < boardSize - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize - 1; i++) {
      board[i][j] = boardLoad.read();
    }
  }

int row = 0;
int col = 0;
String word = "";
dfs(row, col, board, dictionary, hashDict, word);

}

private static void dfs(int r, int c, String[][] board,
                      ArrayList<String> dict, HashSet set, String word) {

word += board[r][c];

boolean isWord = isWord(set, word);
boolean isPrefix = isPrefix(dict, word);

if(!isWord && !isPrefix) {
  return;
} else if (isWord) {
  System.out.println(word);
}

if (r != 0 && isLowerCase(board[r-1][c])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r-1, c, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (r != 0 && c != board.length - 1 && isLowerCase(board[r-1][c+1])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r-1, c+1, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (c != board.length - 1 && isLowerCase(board[r][c+1])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r, c+1, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (r != board.length && c != board.length - 1 && isLowerCase(board[r+1][c+1])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r+1, c+1, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (r != board.length - 1 && isLowerCase(board[r+1][c])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r+1, c, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (r != board.length - 1 && c != 0 && isLowerCase(board[r+1][c-1])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r+1, c-1, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (c != 0 && isLowerCase(board[r][c-1])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r, c-1, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

if (r != 0 && c != 0 && isLowerCase(board[r-1][c-1])) {
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toUpperCase();
  dfs(r-1, c-1, board, word);
  board[r][c] = board[r][c].toLowerCase();
}

}


private static boolean isWord(HashSet<String> hashDict, String word) {
return hashDict.contains(word);
}

private static boolean isPrefix(ArrayList<String> dictionary, String word) {
int lo = 0;
int hi = dictionary.size() - 1;
while(lo <= hi) {
  int mid = lo + (hi - lo)/2;
  if (dictionary.get(mid).startsWith(word)) {
    return true;
  } else if (dictionary.get(mid).compareTo(canonWord) < 0) {
    lo = mid + 1;
  } else {
    hi = mid - 1;
  }
 }
   return false;
}

private static boolean isLowerCase(String str) {
  return str.equals(str.toLowerCase());
}

}
```

Comment: Please start with indenting your code correctly - either by hand or preferably using the "Format Source Code" function of your IDE. I'm sure you'll find a missing `}` or superflous `{` somewhere.

Comment: the problem is within your if block(s) when you recursively attempt to call the "dfs" method, you're passing the incorrect type/amount of arguments. this --> dfs(r-1, c, board, word); is the problem. make sure you add the required amount of arguments and make sure the types match as well.

Comment: You have several compilation errors, the first is `BufferedReader boardLoad = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));` - next is kind of big, your recursive dfs calls don't match the method signature.

Answer (score 1):

Your code have many compiler errors and nothing about that method dfs() is expecting a return type on line 31.

Same compiler errors in your code could be corrected like this:

```
//First line to correct
BufferedReader boardLoad = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0])));

//Second line to correct
board[i][j] = String.valueOf(boardLoad.read());

//Next N lines to correct
dfs(r - 1, c + 1, board, dict, set,word);
```

I recommend you to use any IDE to help to solve your problem